# Find web element (button) by class and Name

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am very new to Selenium.

I am trying to find button Validate (see below) and not to use xpath.

```
<div class="order">
<a style="float: left;" href="#143207" class="VoidDoc ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" role="button"> Void </a>
<a style="float: left;" href="validatedocumentation.php?documentId=143207&amp;origin=viewreferral.php&amp;OrderId=836829" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" role="button"> Validate </a>
<a class="signDocBehalf ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" style="float: left;" href="#143207#20263#836829" role="button">Sign</a>
<a style="float: left;" href="editdocumentation.php?documentId=143207&amp;origin=viewreferral.php" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" role="button"> Edit </a>
</div>
```

I tried to look by a class name (unfortunately not unique) and text of the button ("Validate"):

```
.....Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget' and text()='Validate']")).click();
```

also I tried

```
.....Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget' and text()='Validate']")).click();
```

getting an error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget' and text()='Validate']"}
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)
```

I am guessing it is because `"<a>" is nested in "<div>"` , correct me if I am wrong.

How it would be right to identify this button.

Please, give me your kind advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost correct.

the xpath that you are using

```
//a[@class='ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget' and text()='Validate']
```

is partially correct. There are **trailing spaces for text Validate**, so you'd have to use `contains`

Use this xpath :

```
//a[@class='ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget' and contains(text(),'Validate')]
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Since you've mentioned you do not wanna use xpath, not sure why though ?

If that is the case then please use css selector like this :

```
a.ui-button.ui-corner-all.ui-widget[role='button'][href^='validatedocumentation.php?']
```

Comment: Thank you cruisepandey, This sttement:  //a[@class='ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget' and contains(text(),'Validate')]  is working.  Really appreciate.